# imgaug: is it possible to keep the augmenter at the current transformation?

Tags: python, data-augmentation

I'm working at augmenting a dataset made of sequences of frames: i'd like to apply a particular transformation to all the frames in a sequence, while normally imgaug applies a random transformation (within the given parameters) for each image fed into it.
Say the sequences of augmenters is rotate, flip and zoom:
I'd like to store a particular transformation once applied to the first image, like rotate 30°, flip horizontally, and zoom 0.15%, and apply it to all other images in the sequence.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Chris thank you, mind referencing me to the doc page or telling me how?

Comment: https://github.com/aleju/imgaug   You can create a pipeline which if I recall is multithreaded for performance and you can stack up as many augs as you want and have them applied to all the images the same way